# Issue with CalibratedClassifierCV's fit function when using StackingClassifier + Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, calibration

I have a list of pipeline objects as a list of classifiers. Then I use those classifiers in the `StackingClassifier`. Now I want to apply the `CalibratedClassifierCV` method.

> Note: In the fit function, **the indices of the main data are passed**, not the 2D feature vectors.

```
def input(index_list):
  return main_data[index_list]# return 2d feature vectors

input_function = FunctionTransformer(func= input, validate=False, accept_sparse=False)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
meta_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)

clf1 = Pipeline(steps=[('function_name', input_function), ('clf',clf)])
clf2 = Pipeline(steps=[('function_name', input_function), ('clf',clf)])

X= np.array([1,20,40, 60])# For example
y= np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])# For example

clf1.fit(X,y)# here, I am passing only the indices of the `main data array` and `input` function will return the actual 2d data through the pipeline.
clf2.fit(X,y)

stack_clf = StackingClassifier(classifiers=[clf1, clf2], meta_classifier=meta_clf,use_probas=True, average_probas=False)
    sclfdict_parc_dt.fit(X, y)
```

> Up to here, the fit function of stackingclassifier or pipeline is working perfectly.
>
> Now, I want to apply the `CalibratedClassifierCV` on the `StackingClassifier`.

```
sig_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(stack_clf , method="sigmoid", cv="prefit")
sig_clf.fit(X_test, y_test) # Get errors from the line
```

> Error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>   array=[  2   4  31  33  47 100 117 160 173 375 379 387 401 405 415 426 430 431
>    455]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Can anyone please help on it?